# ORA-06531:Reference to uninitialized collection

Tags: oracle12c

i have a following code in pl/sql anonymous block & getting error "Reference to uninitialized collection".

```
declare 
myarray my_array_type := my_array_type ();
begin
PKG.GETVAL(myarray);
for I in 1..myarray.count
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value : '||myarray(I).value);
end;
```

PKG.GETVAL() returns some values in array.

> ```
> Error report:
> ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection
> ORA-06512: at line 4
> 06531. 00000 -  "Reference to uninitialized collection"
> ```

Comment: It would seem that you haven't instantiated any values into your collection so you cannot then loop through it.

Comment: It would help if this example was cleaned up and was fully reproducible.  There are some syntax errors, GETVAL looks like a procedure and not a function, the error line numbers imply that GETVAL is setting the collection to NULL, etc.